# How to test a component with reduce method in react using react testing and jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to perform using the test on the component I have in my react app. when I simply tried to render my component using the render from react testing it is throwing me the error.

Can anyone please suggest to me the solution to this?  please see the code below:

**Code for testing the authorgroup componenet;**

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import AuthorsGroup from "./Authorsgroup";

it("should render author component", () => {
  render(<AuthorsGroup />);

  const headerEl = screen.getByRole("heading", { name: /happyusertapesh/i });
  expect(headerEl).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**Authorcomponent**

```
const Authorsgroup = ({
  posts,
  groupDropdownValue,
  setShowForm,
  setPostId,
  showForm
}) => {
  const authorGroup = posts.reduce((group, authorgroup) => {
    (group[authorgroup.author.replace(/ +/g, "")] =
      group[authorgroup.author.replace(/ +/g, "")] || []).push(authorgroup);
    return group;
  }, {});
  const [authorGroupValues, setAuthorGroupValues] = useState(authorGroup);

  const authorGroupEntries = Object.entries(authorGroupValues);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAuthorGroupValues(authorGroup);
  }, [groupDropdownValue, showForm]);

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Container style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
          {authorGroupEntries.map(([author, posts]) => {
            return (
              <div key={author}>
                <Accordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                  >
                    <Typography variant="h6" style={{ color: "#EB1283" }}>
                      {author}
                    </Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>

              {posts.map(({ id, text, author, location }) => {
                return (
                  <div key={id}>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                      <Typography variant="h4">
                        {id} {author}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography>
                        {text} {location}
                      </Typography>
                      <Button
                        variant="outlined"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setShowForm(!showForm);
                          setPostId(id);
                        }}
                        startIcon={<EditIcon />}
                      >
                        Edit
                      </Button>
                    </AccordionDetails>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </Accordion>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Container>
  </Container>
</>
  );
};

export default Authorsgroup;
```

Thanks for your help.

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing any props into the test component. This means that the value posts is being set to undefined.

Simply pass a mock value for posts as a prop in the render method

```js
render(<AuthorsGroup posts={/* posts mock value here */} />)
```

You will also need to do this for each of the other props you have defined.